# Spring transaction not rollbacked when an expcetion happen

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I use spring 3.2 and have some transactions. When i get an exception, the rollback don't seem to be done.

My code

```
public class x{

  @Transactional
  public createX(){
  try{
     ...
     y.createY();
     ...
   }
   catch(Exception e){
     ....
   }
 }

}

public class y{
@Transactional
public createY(){
      ...
  callYY();
     ...
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void callYY(){
  ...
  throw new Exception();
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Configuration {
}
```

Basicaly, i have a class X, createX method start a transaction. It call createY who call callYY. 
In this method an exception happen.
I was thinking then all the persistent operation since the createX would be rollbacked but it's not that who happen

I don't see transaction info in the log

any idea

Comment: By default only unchecked exceptions lead to a rollback (i.e. `RuntimeExceptions` and `Error`s not `Exception`s. Next you are catching the exception which also breaks proper tx management as it isn't seen by Spring anymore. So don't catch and either throw a `RuntimeException` or define a `rollbackFor` attribute on `@Transactional`.

Comment: my exception extends RuntimeException

Comment: Then post some code that reflects your code as `new Exception` doesn't express that. But anyway you shouldn't try/catch and swallow exceptions as that breaks proper tx support.

Comment: in the log, i don't see any transaction who are created, don't think it's normal. I have a class with this annotation: @EnableTransactionManagement

Answer (score 1):

Try define exception which cause rollback, for example:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Throwable.class, Exception.class})
```

Comment: with this i could keep the try catch?

Comment: Yes, but I believe you should try..catch your method `createX` not `createY`. Now when exception in `createY` is thrown, its catched in `createX` and no rollback from in `createX` method happens

Answer (score 1):

`Propagation.REQUIRED` (which is default) means that no transaction opened in case of an open transaction exists.
That means that the transaction actually being opened upon calling `x.createX` method and nothing is done (in terms of transaction treatment) upon calling `y.callY` and `y.callYY` methods.

However you catch the exception and it doesn't reach the Spring transaction interceptor defined on `x.createX` method, which should translate it into the rollback.

So if `x.createX` don't have to to be transactional, removing `@Transactional` from it will make the rollbacks to happen.

Comment: or i can also add in the annotation i think rollbackFor =

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. You catch exception in method createX. If you want rollback you can't catch exception in transaction. To rollback transaction you have to throw exception without catch.

Answer (score -1):

You never mention your tranaction manager. You will need to either define a transaction manager in your application context xml...

```
<bean id="txManager"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

OR as an annotated declaration on your Bean Configuration class...

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement()
public class MyConfiguration {...}
```

Comment: One also needs tables that support transactions as well.